# aidl is missing when trying buildToolsVersion "23rc1"

Tags: android

Was just trying out buildTools 23rc1 and the build fails with aidl is missing - this project uses no aidl - I smell a bug in the rc ( it is an rc after all ) - but just want to ask here first before filing a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You use `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1"` in Мodule gradle, than you should use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1'` in Project gradle file.

Comment: I am using buildToolsVersion "23 rc2" in the module and classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1' and still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The aapt and aidl etc. have been moved to \Android SDK\build-tools\23.0.0_rc1\bin in build tools 23.0.0_rc1 irrespective to that of older versions of build tools like 22.0.1,
So to solve this issue-
Go to \Android SDK\build-tools\23.0.0_rc1\bin  and copy all the files and paste them in \Android SDK\build-tools\23.0.0_rc1\ folder ,
Just rename aapt to aapt.exe and paste the aapt one more time (Leave the name unchanged),
Restart the Android studio or Eclipse that you use.It should be solved.

This method can be replaced with the method of Changing the Module settings(
R.Click on project and click on Change module settings) in Android Studio to lower build tools versions like 22.0.1, but in most cases the first method works well.